# Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, elixir, asdf

**Operating system and version: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**

When installing Erlang on my Ubuntu system getting issue of raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection timed out.

```
asdf install erlang 25.1 (or install another version 24.02)
```

[asdf install erlang command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBKXf.png)

**asdf list erlang** command should return erlang version install successfully.

Comment: This is a network glitch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74794022/curl-28-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com-port-443-connection-t)